# Combine two tables based on result from one table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, pdo

I have a two tables. `table1` and `table2`. How can I combine both tables based on `ip_address` from `table1` organized by `ip_address`? So if `ip_address` doesn't exist in `table1`, then do not include it from `table2`.

`table1`:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| page_url |   ip_address    |
+----------+-----------------+
| /        | 123.123.123.123 |
| /page2   | 123.123.123.123 |
| /        | 456.456.456.456 |
| /page9   | 123.123.123.123 |
| /page2   | 456.456.456.456 |
+----------+-----------------+
```

`table2`:

```
+-------------+-----------------+
|  page_url   |   ip_address    |
+-------------+-----------------+
| /contact-us | 456.456.456.456 |
| /about      | 123.123.123.123 |
| /services   | 456.456.456.456 |
| /services   | 789.789.789.789 |
| /about      | 456.456.456.456 |
| /           | 123.123.123.123 |
| /           | 789.789.789.789 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

The final result should look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| page_url    |   ip_address    |
+-------------+-----------------+
| /           | 123.123.123.123 |
| /page2      | 123.123.123.123 |
| /page9      | 123.123.123.123 |
| /about      | 123.123.123.123 |
| /           | 123.123.123.123 |
| /           | 456.456.456.456 |
| /page2      | 456.456.456.456 |
| /contact-us | 456.456.456.456 |
| /services   | 456.456.456.456 |
| /about      | 456.456.456.456 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

First, get `table1`'s results:

```
select table1.page_url, table1.ip_address
from table1
left join table2
on table1.ip_address = table2.ip_address;
```

then the invert:

```
select table2.page_url, table2.ip_address
from table1
left join table2
on table1.ip_address = table2.ip_address
where not (table2.page_url is null);
```

And then take the two queries and union them.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

[**SQL LEFT JOIN**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matching records from the right table (table2). The result is 0 records from the right side, if there is no match.

Answer (score 0):

Left join is the way, so it will only match on values from the first table. This is untested, but should give you the results you want.

```
SELECT t.*, t2.* 
FROM table1 t 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.ip_address = t.ip_address
```

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates. How can I get rid of them?